# What does the pill-shaped 'X' mean in electrical schematics?

Tags: connector, ground, schematics, wire

I'm not familiar with this symbol.
Does it have a name?  What does it imply when reading an electrical schematic?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it signifies a twisted pair.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cables `FL1000B20-WHT` and `FL1000B20-BLU` are twisted pair with additional shield. Look at these symbols:

[image]

Comment: Although I would have guessed 'twisted pair', I'm not familiar with these symbols. Where did you find them? Are they in a standard somewhere?

Comment: Looks to me like these images came from a software package (the truncated description for the leftmost on the second row is a dead giveaway), but which one?

Comment: @Michael It's AutoCAD Electrical.

Answer (score 2):

Those could be indicating differential pairs.  It simply requires you to twist that cable or keep it as close as close to each other on a PCB.  It also needs to be approximately the same length to match their impedances.

Answer (score 0):

To me, that symbol indicates that the two wires are a twisted pair, or possibly just a two-conductor cable, like lamp cord.